# Can "fetch" in code by Zapier perform a GET & POST?

Tags: fetch, zapier

In Zapier, I've set up the zap "Schedule by Zapier" as trigger and "Code by Zapier" as action. Inside the action, "Code by Zapier" I'd like to perform the following: GET an URL & POST to another URL. However, when I use "fetch" in Zapier from this documentation (https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/tree/32b60634434a63865ea3f79edb33d17e40876c9f#usage) the first request (GET) already took 900ms and to do the second request means it would take more than 1sec
to do the action. Zapier doesn't like this. Can anyone help? Thanks, Elco

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this by chaining together two Code zaps.  The first zap does the get (grab a random number from random.org):

"Run Javascript #1"

```js
fetch('https://www.random.org/passwords/?num=1&len=24&format=plain&rnd=new')
    .then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        var output = {id: 1234, rawHTML: body};
        callback(null, output);
    })
    .catch(callback);
```

This call will return a variable called "rawHTML" that you can use in the next part of the chain.

---

"Run Javascript 2"
[Screenshot of inputData variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUlzj.png)

```js
//random.org includes an extra \n in the password, need to clean that up
var cleanpassword = inputData.strPassword.replace(/\n/g, '');

var payload = {firstName: inputData.strFirstName, lastName: inputData.strLastName, username: inputData.strUserName, password: cleanpassword};

var testendpoint = 'http://requestb.in/s523eys5';
//var test = JSON.stringify(payload);
//console.log(test);
     
fetch(testendpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(responsebody) {
        var output = {response: responsebody};
        callback(null, output);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        callback(error);
    });
```

---

It is much much easier to debug this stuff if you use http://requestb.in before you target your real end point.